# Eclipse refactoring plugins

Tags: eclipse, refactoring, eclipse-jdt

I am after more **refactoring** options than the default that comes in Eclipse 3.6. Can anyone list any other plugins that do refactoring and what they do ?

My original problem was i wanted to re-order some type parameter declarations in some classes and unfortunately for me the default refactorings in Eclipse did not support moving them around...

Comment: A refactoring tool for reodering type parameters of a class seems useful. I suggest that you open a bug report and ask for this feature from the Eclipse developers.